# How to store output of phpinfo() in a variable?

Tags: php

Since [phpinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) function returns boolean I was interested to save its output to somewhere.

Comment: No. There are no answers how to STORE content in the variable. So then I can search on it programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with

```php
ob_start();
phpinfo();
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

Then we can search in that string everything we want.
Hope, this would be helpful for somebody, since I didn't find any solution for this on stackoverflow.